# Tailwind CSS: add pattern for responsive classnames to safelist?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I'm using this pattern in the safelist of a project's tailwind config. to include all padding utilities:

```
{ pattern: /^p(\w?)-/ }
```

Is it possible to include responsive utility variants via a pattern as well (i.e. `sm:p-`, `md:p-`, `lg:p-`, ...)?

I've tried the following which tailwind tells me is not a recognized pattern:

```
{ pattern: /^sm:p(\w?)-/ }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [the documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#using-regular-expressions):

> Patterns can only match against base utility names like `/bg-red-.+/`, and won’t match if the pattern includes a variant modifier like `/hover:bg-red-.+/`.
>
> If you want to force Tailwind to generate variants for any matched classes, include them using the `variants` option:

So for your case:

```js
{
  pattern: /^p(\w?)-/,
  variants: ['sm', 'md', 'lg'],
}
```